# custom asp.net identity store - why is HttpContext.Current empty at times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, httpcontext

I've implemented a custom User Store for ASP.NET Identity by following the example set [here](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity2.0-Custom-Database/). That all works fine, except for this:

I need access to data about the currently logged in user in my user store. Normally, you'd access that by accessing

```
HttpContext.Current.User
```

Now, once auser has logged in, if he user then goes to the Manage controller (e.g. to try and change his/her password), when ASP.NET identity looks up the user again by calling

```
CustomUserManager.FindByIdAsync(string userId)
```

HttpContext.Current is empty altogether (that's prior to rendering the page). So, how do I get information about the HttpContext in this scenario? The user is properly logged in, so how do I figure out which user has been logged in?

@edit.. the problem is in CustomUserStore.. here's a bit of it

```
   public class CustomUserStore<TUser> : IUserStore<TUser>, IUserLoginStore<TUser>, IUserClaimStore<TUser>, IUserPasswordStore<TUser>, IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser>, IUserEmailStore<TUser>, IUserPhoneNumberStore<TUser>, 
    IUserLockoutStore<TUser, string>, IUserTwoFactorStore<TUser, string>//, IQueryableUserStore<TUser> 
    where TUser: CustomUser<string>, IUser<string>
{

    string storageFile = @"c:\temp\aspnetusers.json";
    List<TUser> users;

    public CustomUserStore()
    {
        if (File.Exists(storageFile))
        {
            string contents = File.ReadAllText(storageFile);
            users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TUser>>(contents);
            if (users == null)
                users = new List<TUser>();
        }
        else
            users = new List<TUser>();
    }

    #region IUserStore implementation

    public Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        string sessionId = HttpContext.Current?.Session?.SessionID;
        return Task.FromResult<TUser>(users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId));
    }

    public Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        string sessionId = HttpContext.Current?.Session?.SessionID;
        return Task.FromResult<TUser>(users.FirstOrDefault(u => string.Compare(u.UserName, userName, true) == 0));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and it's in the FindByAsync method where HttpContext.Current can be empty.

It happens in the Index method of the AccountController when the model is created

```
   var model = new IndexViewModel
        {
            HasPassword = HasPassword(),
            PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(userId),
            TwoFactor = await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(userId),
            Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(userId),
            BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(userId)
        };
```

And it's the FindById request in the HasPassword method that causes the problem

```
private bool HasPassword()
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user != null)
        {
            return user.PasswordHash != null;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The other 4 requests to the user manager all have a filled out HttpContext.Current. So it appears that it's calls to UserManager that cause the issue.

Comment: Can you show the code where your `HttpContext.User` is empty? Most likely there is no Http request at that time, hence your problem

Comment: Okay, having identified where the problem happens, the solution is obvious bug begs another question. If I rewrite the above to use an async method for HasPassword, and use UserManager.FindByIdAsync, then HttpContext.Current always has a value. But why is that not the case when calling sync methods on the UserManager? Smells like a bug to me.. perhaps UserManager internally calls the Async method and does not restore the context? Time to go check out the source code

Answer (score 1):

Having identified the exact source of the problem, it's easy enough to fix.

Add this async emthod to check if the user has a password:

```
private async Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync()
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user != null)
        {
            return user.PasswordHash != null;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And in the Index method, use the new async methode

```
var model = new IndexViewModel
    {
        HasPassword = await HasPasswordAsync(),
        PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(userId),
        TwoFactor = await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(userId),
        Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(userId),
        BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(userId)
    };
```

But, why does the synchronous method call break things? You'd imagine the sync call would run into the standard context where HttpContext.Current should be available.

I have a more custom User Store in my real project where I run into this problem a lot more frequently.. guess I need to check if contains a lot more synchronous access to UserManager methods.

Comment: ugh, I really wish I'd found this yesterday